# Creating a News Feed Page with updates from people

Tags: php, mysql

Here's a mysql table : `friends` :

```
followed INT, <-- The user's id ( the follower is following him )
followedby INT <-- The follower's id
```

and table `updates` :

```
updateid INT,
updatetext TEXT,
updatetime DATETIME
uid INT
```

A guy with the userid 2 is logged in and want to see the updates of the users he follows.
Right now, he only follows 3 users. To select the updates I can do execute this:

```
SELECT * FROM updates WHERE ( uid=10 , uid=20 OR uid=30 ) ORDERBY updatetime DESC LIMIT 10
```

**Problems**

I want to select the users who are followed by the loggedin user and want to select the updates by those users.
The user can have many friends. Please help.

Comment: in which format you are string user info (followed, followers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use subquery and `IN()`

```
SELECT * 
FROM updates 
WHERE uid IN(SELECT followed FROM friends WHERE followedby = USERS_ID_HERE) 
ORDER BY updatetime DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Just so you know. This SQL query is not correct. It's `friends` and __not__ `followers` you should be sub-querying.

Comment: @Treffynnon : I wanted to know how this thing works, and not the code. I was able to create the News Feed page.

Comment: @Treff yeah, I had "friends" there. I'm not sure why Sergio changed that. rollbacking

Answer (score 2):

Try the following updates to your SQL statement to implement a [sub-select in the where <sup>MySQL Docs</sup>](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html) clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM updates
WHERE uid IN (SELECT followed 
              FROM friends 
              WHERE followedby = '$current_user_id')
ORDER BY updatetime DESC
LIMIT 10
```

`$current_user_id` is the ID of the user who is currently logged into your system.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complex problem (the "user can have many friends" part). If your app grows too big, the database won't fit on a single server and you'll have to shard. That's when you'll run into problems with your existing schema.

Some big sites solve this problem by creating a personal "materialized" newsfeed for each user.

But, I guess, you don't need this right now. See other answers. :-)